# TypeError: argument must be a string or number on column with strings that are numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with categories. In column 4 I have 2 values( two and four which are strings). Do you know why I get the error and how to fix it?TypeError: argument must be a string or number

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:..".py", line 112, in _encode
    res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)

  File "C:...py", line 60, in _encode_python
    uniques = sorted(set(values))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C...".py", line 35, in <module>
    X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X4.fit_transform(X[:, 4])

  File "C:...py", line 252, in fit_transform
    self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)

  File "C:....py", line 114, in _encode
    raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")

TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np #mathematical tools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #plot nice charts
import pandas as pd #import and manage data sets

# Making a list of missing value types
missing_values = ["?"]
df= pd.read_csv('D:\\data.csv',na_values = missing_values)

#print the new table with the missing values 
# print (df)
# print (df.isnull())


X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values #Matrix - independent variables (features)
y = df.iloc[:, 24].values #dependent variables vectors


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X2.fit_transform(X[:, 2]) #gas=0, fuel=1 

labelencoder_X3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X3.fit_transform(X[:, 3])

#I get an error her
labelencoder_X4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X4.fit_transform(X[:, 4])

labelencoder_X5 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 5] = labelencoder_X5.fit_transform(X[:,5])

labelencoder_X6 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 6] = labelencoder_X6.fit_transform(X[:, 6])

labelencoder_X7 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 7] = labelencoder_X7.fit_transform(X[:, 7])

labelencoder_X13 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 13] = labelencoder_X13.fit_transform(X[:, 13])

labelencoder_X14 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 14] = labelencoder_X14.fit_transform(X[:, 14])

labelencoder_X15 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 16] = labelencoder_X14.fit_transform(X[:, 16])

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(X[:, 1:24])  
X[:, 1:24]=imputer.transform(X[:, 1:24])
```

Thank you for the help!

[image: img of the column]

Comment: what is the type of the this column?

Comment: @Siddhant Ranjan a string as you see in the image. The problem in the NAN in the column and I don't know how to impute a column with strings

Comment: you have to fill the nan values in the column, then perform label encoding and it can be of object type too.it's not always what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically occurs when having `NaN` values in a column with strings. `NaN` is of type `float`, and this is why you get:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

You should substitute missing values before anything else. One way to do so:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Making a list of missing value types
missing_values = ["?"]
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\data.csv', na_values=missing_values)


X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, 24]

X.iloc[:, 4] = X.iloc[:, 4].fillna('NaN') # <-- add this line

X.iloc[:, 4] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(X.iloc[:, 4])
```

Now the label encoding shouldn't cause any problems anymore. You will have to do this substitution for all of the columns with strings.

Comment: Thank you! another way to do this is to use a strategy of most_frequent with imputing. It works also on strings!

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to handle missing values. As specified in the answer, this is just _one_ of them ;) The advantage here is that you do not need any extra tools other than what you already had. Otherwise, there are of course options like  [`SimpleImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) around.